# Spy function with elementary JavaScript syntax

Tags: javascript, callback, overloading

How to write a function `spy(fun, callback)` which is an overloaded version of a function `fun` in JavaScript, so that each time `fun` is called, `callback` is called?

For example, in the code below, each time `Math.abs` is called, the console should print the line `The ... called` twice.

```js
function cb() {
  console.log("The call back has been called");
}

Math.abs = spy(Math.abs, cb);
var result = Math.abs(-32);
result = Math.abs(-32);
console.log(result);
```

I found the [following code on GitHub](https://github.com/PardeepBhasin/Problems/blob/857d9c06845aef76dd8f44dfd7cb0d9a098f169a/problems.js) through code search, but the line `The ... called` is printed once and only once no matter how many times `Math.abs` are called.

```js
function spy(fun, callback) {
  if (typeof callback == 'function') {
    callback(fun);
  }
  return fun;
}
```

I tried replacing `callback(fun);` with `callback();`, but it didn't help.  I tried envelopping the code with an anonymous function.

```js
function spy(fun, callback) {
  return (typeof callback == 'function') ? () => {callback(); return fun} : fun;
}
```

This time the number of times that `cb` is called is correct, but the return type is wrong.

Comment: Functions are immutable. You'll have to create a `spy()` function that returns a *new* function, and then call that instead of `fun()`.

Comment: See the linked question's answers for details, but basically in ES5: `function spy(fun, callback) { return function() { try { callback.apply(this, arguments); } catch (e) { } return fun.apply(this, arguments); }; }` In ES2015+: `function spy(fun, callback) { return function(...args) { try { callback.apply(this, args); } catch (e) { } return fun.apply(this, args); }; }` In ES2020+, you can use just `} catch {` instead of `} catch(e) {`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your suggestion.